# How can I get in to an API content that looks like this?

Tags: r, api, post, get, httr

The API specifications

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.com/api/login/adm' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: XXXXXXXXX' \
--data-raw '{
    "usuario" : "XXX",
    "clave" : "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}'
curl --location --request GET 'https://api-.com/api/XX/XX' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX_XXXX' \
--header 'Cookie: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

How can I read it in httr in R? or with another package?

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried? [`?GET`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/GET.html) includes examples with `add_headers` (and `set_cookies`) which solves most of your question, and `POST` has an argument `body=` which will likely handle your `--data-raw`. You might need to set `encode="json"`.

Comment: For clarity, something like `GET(url, add_headers(Authorization=paste("Bearer", mykey))` might be a good start.

Comment: @r2evans Hi! thanks for your comments. It keeps saying Status 405 or 415. I cant fix a syntax error.

Comment: 405 is "method not allowed", 415 is "unsupported media type". You say that the above `curl` statements work without error, returning 200?

Comment: FYI, I missed this before: I don't know if there's an analog for `--location` in `httr`. I don't know that there isn't, but I've not used the argument in `curl` so haven't had the need for it in `httr`. Do you *know* that you need it? Regardless, it might help if you post the R code you've tried.

Comment: @r2evans I would like to get into the api for extract information. It has been passed to me in that format. I have tried this: 
baseUrl <- "https://api/api/login/adm"

a <- POST(baseUrl, 
     body = list(j_username = "xxx", j_password = "xxxx"),
     multipart = FALSE,
     verbose()
)

headers <- add_headers(
  "Content-Type" = "application/json", 
  Accept = "application/json",
  "Accept-Version" = "1.0"
)

ab <- GET(baseUrl, headers, verbose())
Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans I just want to open it in R, no matter what package use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to have a known api endpoint where you can compare results; from [*Getting started with httr*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html), I'll use httpbin.org.

```sh
$ curl --location --request GET 'https://httpbin.org/get' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX_XXXX'
  --header 'Cookie: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": "Bearer XXX_XXXX",
    "Cookie": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.68.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-618be7c3-5c0267582e0de42f05e4d7cc"
  },
  "origin": "172.254.236.28",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

In R, I can replicate that (mostly) with:

```r
library(httr)
library(magrittr) # for %>%, not strictly required, just for demo/vis
GET("https://httpbin.org/get", add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer XXX_XXXX"), set_cookies("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")) %>%
  content(as="text") %>%
  cat(., "\n")
# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
# {
#   "args": {}, 
#   "headers": {
#     "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
#     "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip", 
#     "Authorization": "Bearer XXX_XXXX", 
#     "Cookie": "=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
#     "Host": "httpbin.org", 
#     "User-Agent": "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.1", 
#     "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-618be835-2cab359e06d9bb525f209b8d"
#   }, 
#   "origin": "172.254.236.28", 
#   "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
# }
```

Similarly,

```sh
$ curl --location --request POST 'https://httpbin.org/post' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --header 'Cookie: XXXXXXXXX' \
> --data-raw '{
>     "usuario" : "XXX",
>     "clave" : "XXXXXXXXXXX"
> }'
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\n    \"usuario\" : \"XXX\",\n    \"clave\" : \"XXXXXXXXXXX\"\n}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "54",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.68.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-618be8de-2f1275a05b257ae7245120ae"
  },
  "json": {
    "clave": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "usuario": "XXX"
  },
  "origin": "172.254.236.28",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

and

```r
POST("https://httpbin.org/post", set_cookies("XXXXXXXXX"), body = list(usuario="XXX", clave="XXXXXXXXXXX"), encode="json") %>%
  content(as="text") %>%
  cat(., "\n")
# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
# {
#   "args": {}, 
#   "data": "{\"usuario\":\"XXX\",\"clave\":\"XXXXXXXXXXX\"}", 
#   "files": {}, 
#   "form": {}, 
#   "headers": {
#     "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
#     "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip", 
#     "Content-Length": "39", 
#     "Content-Type": "application/json", 
#     "Cookie": "=XXXXXXXXX", 
#     "Host": "httpbin.org", 
#     "User-Agent": "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.1", 
#     "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-618be94c-20fb2500728a22f43d6a32db"
#   }, 
#   "json": {
#     "clave": "XXXXXXXXXXX", 
#     "usuario": "XXX"
#   }, 
#   "origin": "172.254.236.28", 
#   "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
# }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
thanks for the patience, this was helpful!!

Comment: could you help me with my last problem? I'm able to enter the api but the data appears in the console, how can I extract it in csv or in an object (data frame)?

Comment: It depends a little on how it's coming across, but in this example I can use `res <- content(POST(...))`, and then `mydata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res)`. If your response is json, then use that; if it's raw CSV text, then perhaps `mydata <- read.csv(text=res)`. Does that work/help?

Comment: Thanks! This doesn´t work.
> mydata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res)
Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
> mydata <- read.csv(text=res)
Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid 'text' argument

Comment: I really can't know without seeing what the results look like. What are you expecting? Can you give a sample of the output?